# RunShellScript in Azure Linux VM to change hostname is not working

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I have deployed Azure Linux VM from DevOps. If I can see the hostname, it appears as golden image name itself.
I want to change the computer name or hostname from DevOps itself. I executed the command below it shows succeed but it wont change the hostname.

```
$script="sudo hostnamectl set-hostname vm-10.64.157.148"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VMName -ScriptString $script -CommandId 'RunShellScript'
```

Later I am trying to execute same command from Portal using RunCommand option, its throwing below error

```
[stderr]
sudo: Account or password is expired, reset your password and try again
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: unable to change expired password: Authentication token manipulation error
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created Linux VM in Azure. When I logged into the VM and checked the hostname, it was `vmlinuxvjy` as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

> I want to change the computer name or hostname from DevOps itself.

Add `Azure Powershell task` in pipeline and create service connection for authentication and then add the Inline script.

```
$script="sudo hostnamectl set-hostname vm-10.64.157.148"
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rg-vjy' -Name 'vmlinuxvjy' -ScriptString $script -CommandId 'RunShellScript'
```

[image]

Run the pipeline and checkout the result.
[image]

I will also verify the hostname change in the Linux VM:
[image]

When executing the hostname change command in the Azure portal, make sure to execute only one command:

```
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname vm-10.64.157.148
```

[image]

If you encounter any password authentication issues, try resetting the password:
[image]